# How do I run docker on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have an aws code pipeline which currently successfully deploys code to my EC2 instances.

I have a Docker image that has the necessary setup to run my code, Dockerfile provided below. When I run `docker run -t` it just loads up an interactive shell on my docker but then hangs on any command (eg: ls)

Any advice?

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda2

RUN apt-get install git

ENV PYTHONPATH /app/phdcode/panaxeaA1

# setting up venv
RUN conda create --name panaxea -y
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate panaxea"

# Installing necessary packages
RUN conda install -c guyer pysparse
RUN conda install -c conda-forge pympler
RUN pip install pysparse
RUN git clone https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy.git
RUN cd fipy && python setup.py install

RUN cd ~

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN cd panaxeaA1/models/alpha04c/launchers
RUN echo "launching..."
CMD python launcher_260818_aws.py
```

Comment: What's AWS-specific about this?  Does it work locally?  What's your actual `docker run` command or equivalent?

Comment: Did you try with `docker run -i -t`?

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -t` simply starts a docker container with a [pseuodo-tty](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#usage) connection to the container's stdin. However, just running this command does not establish an interactive shell to the container. You will need this to be able to have run commands within your container.

You need to also append the `-i` command line flag along with the shell you wish to use. For example, `docker run -it IMAGE_NAME bash` will launch a container from the image you provide using bash as your interactive shell. You can then run Bash commands as you normally would.

If you are looking for a simple way to run containers on EC2 instances in AWS, I highly recommend [AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) as an option. It is a very simple service for running containers that abstracts and manages much of the server level work involved in running containers.